# pdftk does not update PageLabel metadata

Tags: pdf, file-metadata, pdftk

I realised that `pdftk` does not update the `PageLabel` metadata, when using `update_data_utf8`. I've got a pdf file (let's call it `file.pdf`), which contains the metadata

```
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 1
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelNumStyle: LowercaseLetters
PageLabelBegin
PageLabelNewIndex: 3
PageLabelStart: 1
PageLabelNumStyle: LowercaseRomanNumerals
```

If I issue the commands

```
pdftk file.pdf dump_data_utf8 > data.txt
pdftk file.pdf cat 1-end output file2.pdf
pdftk file2.pdf update_info_utf8 data.txt output file2_updated.pdf
```

I would expect that `file2_updated.pdf` contains the same metadata as `file.pdf`. However, all `PageLabel` metadata is lost. Though the `Bookmark` metadata, and hence the table of contents, is preserved.

What is happening here? Did I make a mistake, or is that a bug in `pdftk`? For reference, I use version 2.02, which appears to be [the newest one](https://www.pdflabs.com/docs/pdftk-version-history/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not doing anything wrong, pdftk never supported updating page labels (although the code suggests it was a planned feature). If you want to keep using software based on pdftk I suggest the fork [pdftk-java](https://gitlab.com/pdftk-java/pdftk), which implements this missing feature. Disclaimer: I maintain pdftk-java.

Comment: Thank you for maintaining a continuation of this great software!

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same functionality but pdftk 3.0.9 (default version at Ubuntu 20.04) was not working. I have downloaded the most recent version of pdftk from GitHub (3.2.0) and it works like a charm.